# How to use a stack to stretch a string input k times

Tags: c++, recursion, stack

> A stretch of the input string is generated by repeating each character
>   in order up to k times (and at least once). For input string “abc” and
>   k = 2, the output list should have: abc, aabc, abbc, abcc, aabbc,
>   aabcc, abbcc, aabbcc.

I have spent so long trying to figure this out, I can't get the logic. This is what I have so far. It's a very rough attempt as Im only trying to repeat each character up to 2 times to try to get something working :/.

```
class Ana
{
    public:
        string in_str;
        int len;
        int counter;
}; 

List stretch(string input, int k) {
List final_output; // generate empty list
    stack<class Ana> recurStack; // empty stack that performs the recursion
    Ana init, stacktop, orig; // create a pair to push, to start the stack
    orig.in_str = input; // put the initial string
    orig.len = 0; // this is the fixed string, initially empty
    init.in_str = input; // put the initial string
    init.counter = 0;
    init.len = -1; 
    recurStack.push(init); // push this pair onto the top

    while(!recurStack.empty()) // while the stack is non-empty
    {    
        stacktop = recurStack.top();// get the top pair in stack 
        recurStack.pop(); // remove the top element of stack
        if (stacktop.counter == (input.length() - 1)) 
        {
            final_output.insert(stacktop.in_str); // insert the fixed string onto list
            continue; // pop the next element of stack
        }
        char to_ignore;
        if(stacktop.counter == 1) {
                to_ignore = orig.in_str[stacktop.len];
        }



        for(int i = 0; i < stacktop.in_str.length(); i++) {
            if(to_ignore == stacktop.in_str[i])
                continue;
            char to_insert = stacktop.in_str[i];
            Ana temp;
            temp.in_str = stacktop.in_str;
            temp.len = stacktop.len;
            temp.counter = stacktop.counter;
            temp.in_str.insert(i, 1, to_insert);
            (temp.len) = i;
            (temp.counter)++;
            recurStack.push(temp);
        }       
    }
    return final_output;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please show a [mcve] of what you have tried, and explain where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that I do not fully understand the question. Anyway, I will show you a very simple solution, but without using a stack. If you have requirements to use a stack, a recursive calls or whatever, then please comment and I will develop a new answer.

But let us look on the algorithm first. What you need, is some kind of "combination of sub sets" of all letters. The correct approach is to use a so called [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) and to calculate all needed subsets. That is very simple using the binary representation of the overall number of subsets. For all sub-sets of the power-set, where a bit is set, we will stretch the corresponding letter.

Stretch means in this context simply, to repeat it k times.

Caveat. Becuase we use an `unsigned long long` as the powerset ID, we can handle strings with maximum length of 64. But believe me. This would result in that many subsets, so that you computer cannot handle it.

So, the resulting code is rather simple, but needs 3 nested loops.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// Make typing easier
using ULL = unsigned long long;

std::list<std::string> stretch(std::string input, size_t k)
{
    // Resulting list. Initialize with given string
    std::list<std::string> result{ input };

    // Go through all requested depths
    for (size_t depth = 0U; depth < k-1; ++depth) {

        // Go through all possible power-set sub-sets for selecting 1 or more letters
        for (ULL subSetID = 1ULL ; subSetID < (1ULL << static_cast<ULL>(input.size())); ++subSetID) {

            // Bit mask, for checking, if a bit in the sub-set is set
            ULL bitMask{ 1ULL };

            // In here, we build the string from a letter or stretched letter
            std::string temp{};

            // Go through all letters of the input string
            for (const char letter : input) {

                // Check, if the bit mask for this powerset element is set, then stretch, else. take letter as is
                temp += std::string(1, letter) + (((subSetID & bitMask) == bitMask) ? std::string(depth + 1, letter) : "");

                // Check next bit
                bitMask <<= 1;
            }
            // Store the new found string in the resulting list
            result.push_back(temp);     
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // Test for string abc with depth 2
    std::list<std::string> l{ stretch("abc",2) };

    // Show result on screen
    std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```